# Node Zlib. Unzip response with file structure in-memory

Tags: node.js, zlib, unzip

I'm receiving a Buffer `data` from a response with data in a file.

```
// Save it just to check if content is correct
const fd = fs.openSync('data.zip', 'w')
fs.writeSync(fd, data)
fs.closeSync(fd)
```

Produces file `data.zip`, which contains file `foo.csv`.

I can unzip it with `UZIP` in-memory with:

```
const unzipArray = UZIP.parse(data)['foo.csv']
```

However, I cannot do it with Zlib.

```
const unzipArray = zlib.unzipSync(data)
// Rises: incorrect header check
```

It looks like Zlib cannot parse the file structure.

How to unzip the above buffer **in-memory** with Zlib, without saving files to the filesystem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a zip file, not a zlib or gzip stream. As you found, zlib doesn't process zip files. There are many solutions out there for node.js, which you can find using your friend google. Here is [one](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip).

Comment: Mark, do you know a simple lib for parsing only the file structure. I want minimum third party deps, so I prefer to use Zlib for async decompressing. I know the exact file I want to unzip.

Comment: No. But it should be relatively straightforward, though a bit tedious, to write your own parser. The format is fully documented [here](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).

Answer (score -1):

for single file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const zlib = require('zlib');

const fileContents = fs.createReadStream('./data/file1.txt.gz');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./data/file1.txt');
const unzip = zlib.createGunzip();

fileContents.pipe(unzip).pipe(writeStream);
```

for a group of file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const zlib = require('zlib');

const directoryFiles = fs.readdirSync('./data');

directoryFiles.forEach(filename => {
  const fileContents = fs.createReadStream(`./data/${filename}`);
  const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(`./data/${filename.slice(0, -3)}`);
  const unzip = zlib.createGunzip();
  fileContents.pipe(unzip).pipe(writeStream);
});
```

Comment: `data` is received from http response and there are no files in the filesystem. How to unzip it in memory?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#compressing-http-requests-and-responses --> here node explain how to do it :)